# Office 365 About me link is missing

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, mysite

I have an Office 365 account. In SharePoint site collection I am not able to see "About Me" link.

Only tenant admin can see this link. 
Any specific permission required for that?

Comment: I found the solution. For about me link user must be licenced

Comment: it must be a **licenced user** before the link can be avialable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. For about me link . 
**user must be licenced**